# Something Is Using Up Most GPU Memory Not Letting Me Train Models with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After a restart and without touching anything else, I open up the Jupyter Notebook and attempt to run the cells that get the GPU to start training.
But in my Terminal I get this message and in the Notebook I get the long error below. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Keras with Tensorflow backend).

```
87] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.582
pciBusID 0000:25:00.0
Total memory: 10.91GiB
Free memory: 396.44MiB
```

Code of the notebook here https://github.com/fastai/courses/blob/master/deeplearning1/nbs/lesson1.ipynb
In cell [5] I've lowered the batch size to 10 and then tried 5. I also set no_of_epochs=5. In addition to restarts I've also tried looking for any command that gets the system to drop any processes the GPU might be using, but it doesn't appear to be using any.
cell [7] is the cell that gives all the errors below when it is run.

This is the full error under the cell [7] that is trying to utilize the GPU.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2b6861506a11> in <module>()
----> 1 vgg = Vgg16()
      2 # Grab a few images at a time for training and validation.
      3 # NB: They must be in subdirectories named based on their category
      4 batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'train', batch_size=batch_size)
      5 val_batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'valid', batch_size=batch_size*2)

/home/eagle/fastai/courses-master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.pyc in __init__(self)
     45     def __init__(self):
     46         self.FILE_PATH = 'http://files.fast.ai/models/'
---> 47         self.create()
     48         self.get_classes()
     49 

/home/eagle/fastai/courses-master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.pyc in create(self)
    137 
    138         fname = 'vgg16.h5'
--> 139         model.load_weights(get_file(fname, self.FILE_PATH+fname, cache_subdir='models'))
    140 
    141 

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.pyc in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
   2706             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f)
   2707         else:
-> 2708             self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
   2709 
   2710         if hasattr(f, 'close'):

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.pyc in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(self, f)
   2792                         weight_values[0] = w
   2793                 weight_value_tuples += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)
-> 2794             K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
   2795 
   2796     def load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(self, f):

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in batch_set_value(tuples)
   1879             assign_ops.append(assign_op)
   1880             feed_dict[assign_placeholder] = value
-> 1881         get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
   1882 
   1883 

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in get_session()
    123         session = _SESSION
    124     if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
--> 125         _initialize_variables()
    126     return session
    127 

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in _initialize_variables()
    280         sess = get_session()
    281         if hasattr(tf, 'variables_initializer'):
--> 282             sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_variables))
    283         else:
    284             sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(uninitialized_variables))

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
     [[Node: random_uniform_13/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=87654321, seed2=755436606, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](random_uniform_13/shape)]]

Caused by op u'random_uniform_13/RandomUniform', defined at:
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 281, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 232, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 397, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-2b6861506a11>", line 1, in <module>
    vgg = Vgg16()
  File "vgg16.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.create()
  File "vgg16.py", line 134, in create
    self.FCBlock()
  File "vgg16.py", line 113, in FCBlock
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/models.py", line 332, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 546, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/layers/core.py", line 798, in build
    constraint=self.W_constraint)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 418, in add_weight
    weight = initializer(shape, name=name)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/initializations.py", line 66, in glorot_uniform
    return uniform(shape, s, name=name)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/initializations.py", line 33, in uniform
    return K.random_uniform_variable(shape, -scale, scale, name=name)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.2.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 634, in random_uniform_variable
    low, high, dtype=tf_dtype, seed=seed)(shape)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 236, in random_uniform
    shape, dtype, seed=seed1, seed2=seed2)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_random_ops.py", line 263, in _random_uniform
    seed=seed, seed2=seed2, name=name)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/eagle/anaconda3/envs/les1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
     [[Node: random_uniform_13/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=87654321, seed2=755436606, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](random_uniform_13/shape)]]
```

Comment: What does `nvidia-smi` say? It should list running processes under the GPU stats

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't realize that showed usage. Yes. The directory and env I launch the notebook from is using almost all 11gigs of the memory even after I close the notebook and the Terminal window.

Comment: After a restart there are no GPU processes. Then I run the cell once and I always have to run it again because of some directory it never finds the first time. Tried a few commands to kill it. Guess I'll keep looking.

Comment: If you are defying your model multiple times - a memory from `GPU` is not freed. This might cause your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
nvidia-smi
```

The last line will show the process with a 'pid' number
Enter with the 'pid' number last
with the following command (your four digit number at the end will be your own)

```
sudo kill -9 3096
```